# Batch File: Reading Floating Point Values from a .csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file, floating-point

I have made a batch file that reads a .csv file. It then proceeds to take the values from a specific column (in this case, the 4th) and find the highest value. The script works perfectly fine with whole numbers, but once I attempt to pass in a .csv file featuring floating point numbers, the script only reads the first number. ie, 1.546 = 1, 0.896 = 0, etc...

How do I read the floating points normally? In this case, at least 2 points of precision (though the values can be up to 6 points of precision with the real .csv file)

One other thing to note is that this prints out "missing operator" 3 times. I THINK this may be due to spacing, but am not sure where.

The script is as follows:

```
@echo off

set cur=0
set max=0

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in ("sample.csv") do (call :func "%%d")
echo Max is %max%
goto :here

:func
 set /a cur=%1
 if %cur% gtr %max% (set /a max=%cur%)
 goto :eof

:here

pause
```

This is sample.csv, which works fine:

```
1,2,,3,3,5,,
5,6,,7,12.3,6,,
9,10,,11,11.4,7,,
13,14,,15,10.1,2,,
```

I threw in some additional commas, just to test the code.

Comment: well, no, you cannot do fractions by default using batch file. I would strongly recommend powershell, That being said, you cannot just add commas for the purpose of testing something. a csv file has a format, typically the content should match the header, if you add things as you please, it makes no sense.

Comment: Gerhard, I'll look into powershell, thank you. That being said, the real .csv which is generated my another program, has points where there are empty columns, which appear as ",,". I just wanted to see if the for-loop would skip over that or throw some error. Additionally, it doesn't seem to count that as a column, as going to the 4th column still reaches the 3, 12.3, 11.4 and 10.1, in the example above

Comment: Yes, that is understandable as not all fields will have values, but your columns will be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to do actual calculations, then I would not recommend `batch-file` for this while using fractions, but to simply test the highest value, we can split the string by `.` match either side. You can still not use `set /a` to make it an actual integer though:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0 & set frac=0 
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in ("sample.csv") do (
  for /f "tokens=1* delims=." %%i in ("%%~d") do (
      if not "%%j" == "" if %%i gtr !num! (
         set "num=%%i"
         set "max=%%~d"
  )
      if %%i geq !num! if %%~j gtr !frac! (
         set "frac=%%~j"
         set "max=%%~d"
    )
  )
)
echo Max is %max%
pause
```

As per your comment on `~` here is an extract from `for /?`

```
In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
You can now use the following optional syntax:

    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
    %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
    %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
    %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
    %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable and expands %I to the
                   fully qualified name of the first one found.
                   If the environment variable name is not
                   defined or the file is not found by the
                   search, then this modifier expands to the
                   empty string

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

    %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
    %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
    %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
    %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable for %I and expands to the
                   drive letter and path of the first one found.
    %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line

In the above examples %I and PATH can be replaced by other valid
values.  The %~ syntax is terminated by a valid FOR variable name.
Picking upper case variable names like %I makes it more readable and
avoids confusion with the modifiers, which are not case sensitive.
```

Comment: This actually worked perfectly well. Thank you! But what do the tilda's mean? Like in ("%%~d")?

Comment: it is used to define how variables are expanded. So in this instance it simply removes surrounding double quotes. Though it is most probably not required here, there might be a change the number is surrounded by double quotes. i.e `9,10,,11,"11.4",7,,`. You can see all the options for expanding variables by running `for /?` but I took the liberty of copying that specific portion into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, you could use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) for this task. Here's a basic idea.

For the example file content:

```
1,2,,3,3,5,,
5,6,,7,12.3,6,,
9,10,,11,11.4,7,,
13,14,,15,10.1,2,,
```

You could use something like:

```powershell
Import-Csv -Path ".\sample.csv" -Header ("A","B","C","D","E") | Sort-Object { [Single]$_.E } -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty E
```

Which should return:

```
12.3
```

As you can see above, because you had not supplied the header record, I had to create some in order to identify my target field. However, if you already have known header fields, you could simplify the code a little.

For the example file content:

```
This,Is,My,Actual,Header,Record,,
1,2,,3,3,5,,
5,6,,7,12.3,6,,
9,10,,11,11.4,7,,
13,14,,15,10.1,2,,
```

You would just name your field according to its header value name, something like:

```powershell
Import-Csv -Path ".\sample.csv" | Sort-Object { [Single]$_.Header } -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Header
```

Which should, once again, return:

```
12.3
```

Comment: Yes, powershell is clearly the better solution here! Compared to my answer, whixh does work, the ps code is just much less and not a hack.

Comment: I would suggest @Gerhard, that your answer is selected regardless. My answer does not fulfill the question parameters because `PowerShell` is not mentioned, there is no [[tag:powershell]] tag, and I have not provided the code in a way which can be run directly from a [tag:batch-file].